# Nuget package update issues

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package

I am having problems updating Nuget packages in Visual Studio 2013 for a solution.

I right-clicked the solution, chose "Manage packages for solution", then choose "Update All" in the update tab.

It all seemed to update fine, however, in the update tab, the packages that were updated are still showing as needing to update. If I then go to update them again, the list of projects shows each project that has the package, and each checkbox is disabled, as if it already knows they have been updated. So as far as I can tell, every project has been updated.

I have restarted Visual Studio

Anyone else come across this before?

Comment: Haven't have that issue but have you tried updating using the console? (check if there are any error messages) also, it might be an idea to check the packages folder in your solution, are the new versions there?  Another thing to check in your packages.config if the package requests a specific version

Comment: I have looked at one of the packages. It is referenced by 3 projects. All 3 projects are referencing the most up to date version. The packages.config for each project shows it referencing the latest version. Going into the package manager console, it doesn't show this package is needing an update. However, when viewing all packages that are needing an update for the solution it is still showing that that package has an update.

Comment: if you follow the reference of the project and it points to the correct version and you navigate to the nuget gallery and the versions are the same, then I asume the VS2013 nuget extension is faulty

Comment: Good suggestion, however I have just opened it up in VS2012, and the same issue is there.

Comment: Need more infor to be able to help. can you reproduce on a new project? referencing the same packages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check your packages folder.  It seems to me that this problem occurs when Nuget cannot, for whatever reason, delete the old package version.  So if you've got a "MyLib 4.0.3.0" folder and a "MyLib 4.0.5.0" folder, then it will show both of them in the list of installed packages, and it will think that MyLib needs to be updated.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  I had this problem and it solved it for me.

Comment: Me too. deleted the packages folder, restored all packages, and the "update" window of the "manage packages for solution" was fixed.